# Webflux error - no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exists so that Flux<UUID> conforms to Mono<>

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I use Spring Boot and Webflux.

IN my code I try to return a Flux but I get the following error from intellij and the code is marked red:

```
no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exists so that Flux<UUID> conforms to Mono<>
```

My code:

```
public Flux<UUID> deleteCCProtections(Mono<ProtectionSetRequest> protectionSetRequest) {
        return protectionSetRequest.flatMap(
            request ->
                protectionSetRepository
                    .findByProtectionSetIdIn(request.getProtectionSetIds())
                    .collectList()
                    .flatMap(
                        protectionSet ->  //this line is marked red in Intellij
                            deleteCCProtectionset(protectionSet, request.getDeleteBackups()))); //this line is marked red in Intellij
    }
    
    private Flux<UUID> deleteCCProtectionset(
        List<ProtectionSet> protectionSets, boolean deleteRecoveryPoints) {
        return Flux.fromIterable(protectionSets)
            .flatMap(
                protectionSet ->
                    protectorRepository
                        .findByProtectionId(protectionSet.getProtectionId())
                        .flatMap(
                            protector ->
                                Mono.zip(
                                    protectBatchService.delete(protector),
                                    protectionSetRepository.delete(protectionSet))
                                    .flatMap(
                                        tuple ->
                                            protectionService.sendUnprotectCommand(
                                                tuple.getT1()))
                                    .doOnNext(subscriptionResourceService::cancelSubscriptionResources)
                                    //
                                    // .doOnNext(agentDataServiceApi::setProtectedResources) //void
                                    .doOnNext(schedulerService::deleteProtection))); //void
    }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

When I remove Mono from parameters deleteCCProtections(Mono protectionSetRequest the my code compiles - why??? I get Mono from controller to service...

Working code but without Mono

```
public Flux<UUID> deleteCCProtections(ProtectionSetRequest protectionSetRequest) {
        return protectionSetRepository
                 .findByProtectionSetIdIn(protectionSetRequest.getProtectionSetIds())
                    .collectList()
                    .flatMapMany(
                        protectionSet ->  //this line is marked red in Intellij
                            deleteCCProtectionset(protectionSet, request.getDeleteBackups()))); //this line is marked red in Intellij
    }
    
    private Flux<UUID> deleteCCProtectionset(
        List<ProtectionSet> protectionSets, boolean deleteRecoveryPoints) {
        return Flux.fromIterable(protectionSets)
            .flatMap(
                protectionSet ->
                    protectorRepository
                        .findByProtectionId(protectionSet.getProtectionId())
                        .flatMap(
                            protector ->
                                Mono.zip(
                                    protectBatchService.delete(protector),
                                    protectionSetRepository.delete(protectionSet))
                                    .flatMap(
                                        tuple ->
                                            protectionService.sendUnprotectCommand(
                                                tuple.getT1()))
                                    .doOnNext(subscriptionResourceService::cancelSubscriptionResources)
                                    //
                                    // .doOnNext(agentDataServiceApi::setProtectedResources) //void
                                    .doOnNext(schedulerService::deleteProtection))); //void
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `deleteCCProtectionset` returns `Flux<UUID>` you should use `flatMapMany` instead of `flatMap` in `deleteCCProtections` method.

```
public Flux<UUID> deleteCCProtections(Mono<ProtectionSetRequest> protectionSetRequest) {
    return protectionSetRequest.flatMapMany(request -> protectionSetRepository
            .findByProtectionSetIdIn(request.getProtectionSetIds())
            .collectList()
            .flatMapMany(protectionSet -> deleteCCProtectionset(protectionSet, request.getDeleteBackups())));
}
```

Comment: When I changed flatMap to flatMapMany my code still doesn't compile - this time there is the following problem in method deleteCCProtections: required type Flux<UUID>, Provided: Mono<Object>

Comment: You should also change the first `flatMap` to `flatMapMany` since right now it also returns `Flux` from nested lambda `(request -> ...)`. Code updated